# How to group dataframe and calculate geomean?

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, geometric-mean

I have a `df` with a column with dates (`data`) and column with average daily change of price (`DailyChange`) and I need to group this `df` by year and for each year count the geometric mean from column `DailyChange`.

This is the part of the code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("data_with_changes.csv")
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"])

df_result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="data", freq="Y"))["DailyChange"].apply(lambda x: stats.gmean(x.dropna() + 100) - 100).reset_index()

df_result.columns = ["Year", "GeometricMean"]
df_result["Year"] = df_result["Year"].dt.year
df_result.to_csv("average_daily_change.csv", index=False)
```

Don't know where is the problem, if in grouping or in using the `stats.gmean` function wrong.

Comment: Please format your posts properly.

Answer (score 0):

> ou need to subtract 100 from the geometric mean result to convert it back to a percentage change

```js
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

df = pd.read_csv("data_with_changes.csv")
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"])

df_result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="data", freq="Y"))["DailyChange"].apply(lambda x: stats.gmean(x.dropna()) - 100).reset_index()

df_result.columns = ["Year", "GeometricMean"]

df_result["Year"] = df_result["Year"].dt.year

df_result.to_csv("average_daily_change.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: like that its giving me NaN values. With my original function, its giving me values, but also negative ones, which is also wrong.